# Could not send emails to users defined inside a custom site column, using List workflow

Tags: list, workflow, publishing-site, site-column, enterprise-wiki

I have created a simple workflow using SharePoint designer, with the following settings:-

- Start workflow when an item is created or changes:-

[image]

- To send email to the “Assigned to Approvals”.

[image]

- The email settings is :-

[image]

But if I create or modify a wiki page no email is being sent & also when I checked the “Site setting -- workflow settings” I can not find the “test” workflow I have created and published inside the SharePoint designer .

please note that my outgoing email is configured correctly , because user alerts are sending emails. also the "Assigned To Approves" is a custom column with the following settings:-

[image]

can anyone advice please what is causing this problem ?

Comment: Are you making updates with System Account? Can you try any other account..

Comment: You mean system account for creating the workflow ? or for creating wiki pages ?

Comment: Did you try any other account, workflows do not run under System Account.. This was a security update introduced in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: unfortunelty i can only access the server using my account which is also a system account. so is there any way to get around this? as this is a test server so i have defined my account to be a system account also ?

Comment: If its a test server, create another as well.. give proper permissions so that he can execute workflow and see how it works..